# Приоритет использования PV в LVM

Tags: linux, lvm

Где задается приоритет использования PV при выделении места в LVM-группе?
Например если я расширяю существующий логический раздел - как заранее понять на каком диске будет выделено место и где это можно настраивать глобально? (про то что можно параметр передать в конкретную команду я знаю).

Comment: посмотрите исходники или задайте вопрос в рассылке разработчиков. http://www.sourceware.org/lvm2/